# RegOpenKeyEx can't find registry key

Tags: c++, windows, registry

My program is supposed to enumerate installed OPOS devices. They are listed in the registry so I use `RegOpenKeyEx` like this:

```
LONG lResult = RegOpenKeyEx( HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, _T("SOFTWARE\\OLEforRetail\\ServiceOPOS\\PosPrinter"), 0, KEY_READ , &key );
```

It works fine on my computer but behaves very strangely on another machine (windows 7 sp1 32bit).

I have two almost identical test projects (both are mfc dialog applications, the main difference is one is created with visual studio 2005 and another in 2010). In one of those projects the code above works fine, in another `RegOpenKeyEx` returns `ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND`. Also, that key can not be found with regedit.exe.

What is even happening here?

Comment: Could it be a [registry virtualisation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa965884(v=vs.85).aspx)  problem ? On the other hand if regedit __and__ your program cannot find the key it's possibly because the key doesen't exist.

Answer (score 3):

> *Also, that key can not be found with regedit.exe.*

Well, you need to ensure you are accessing Registry with correct bit-ness. On 64-bit OS, "regedit.exe" will open 64-bit view, not 32-bit. You need to use `Windows\syswow64\regedit.exe` to open 32-bit view.

> You cannot open both 32-bit as well as 64-bit **regedit.exe**, at the same time.

For your program, you need to check if it is 32-bit or 64-bit. You also need to check if you have got the permission (check UAC flag in linker).

Once you get it all, you can move on to enable or disable registry redirection so as a 32-bit process can access 64-bit registy, or a 64-bit can open 32-bit view of registry.

Comment: The machine it doesn't work on is a 32-bit machine, according to the question, so I wouldn't think is the problem.